# geofence to detect other device

Tags: android, monitoring, android-geofence

We are trying to build a geofence such that we can detect other devices in the fence (it is alright if we need to install some application on the devices to be detected as well). We are following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fMCQQmkHj8&t=844s) along with [the respective github repository](https://github.com/delaroy/AndroidGeoFencing)

Here is the code for detection, it works fine... As it detects the same device which creates the fence from entering and exiting it. What we want is to detect other devices.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    // Handling errors
    if ( geofencingEvent.hasError() ) {
        String errorMsg = getErrorString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode() );
        Log.e( TAG, errorMsg );
        return;
    }

    int geoFenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
    // Check if the transition type is of interest
    if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT ) {
        // Get the geofence that were triggered
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

        String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(geoFenceTransition, triggeringGeofences );

        // Send notification details as a String
        sendNotification( geofenceTransitionDetails );
    }
}


private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(int geoFenceTransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
    // get the ID of each geofence triggered
    ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences ) {
        triggeringGeofencesList.add( geofence.getRequestId() );
    }

    String status = null;
    if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER )
        status = "Entering ";
    else if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
        status = "Exiting ";
    return status + TextUtils.join( ", ", triggeringGeofencesList);
}

private void sendNotification( String msg ) {
    Log.i(TAG, "sendNotification: " + msg );

    // Intent to start the main Activity
    Intent notificationIntent = MainActivity.makeNotificationIntent(
            getApplicationContext(), msg
    );

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    // Creating and sending Notification
    NotificationManager notificatioMng =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    notificatioMng.notify(
            GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
            createNotification(msg, notificationPendingIntent));

}

// Create notification
private Notification createNotification(String msg, PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location)
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setContentText("Geofence Notification!")
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    return notificationBuilder.build();
}
```

We want changes such that one device creates the geofence and when other devices enter the fence, they can be detected by the device that created and is monitoring the fence. There is no problem if we need to install an app on the devices that are to be detected.

Till now, what we have achieved is that the device that creates the geofence gets a notification if it itself enters or exits the fence...

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: No. Dropped the geofence idea and started checking the distances among the phones using gps coordinates.